# How to integrate the following equation?

Tags: calculus, integration

I am just little bit confused how to solve this differential equation? Please anyone help me
$$(dy/dx) =(y(3-y-2x)) /(x(3-x-2y)) $$

Comment: WA says this here $$\text{Solve}\left[\frac{2 x e^{-4 \tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{x-4 y(x)}{2 y(x)+x}\right)} \left(x
   y(x) \left(18 c_1-4 \log \left(\frac{4 x}{2 y(x)+x}\right)+4 \log \left(\frac{8 y(x)}{2
   y(x)+x}\right)+3\right)+2 x^2-2 y(x)^2\right)}{9 (x-y(x)) y(x)^2}=\frac{4
   x}{3},y(x)\right]$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y\cdot(3-y-2x)}{x\cdot(3-x-2y)} $$
$$ (2xy+y^2-3y)dx+(2xy+x^2-3x)dy = 0$$
$$ P(x,y) = 2xy+y^2-3y, Q(x,y) = 2xy+x^2-3x$$
$$\frac{\partial P(x,y)}{\partial x}=2x+2y-3=\frac{\partial Q(x,y)}{\partial x}$$
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=2xy+y^2-3y,\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=2xy+x^2-3x$$
$$u(x,y) = \int (2xy+y^2-3y)dx = x^2y+y^2x-3yx + \phi(y)$$
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = x^2+2yx-3x+\phi'(y)$$
$$2yx+x^2-3x=x^2+2yx-3x+\phi'(y)$$
$$\phi'(y)=0 ⇒ \phi(y) = 0$$
$$u(x,y) = y^2x+yx^2-3yx$$
$$y^2x+yx^2-3yx = C$$